# Evaluate Words Based on "Rules" (Skeptics.SE Crossover)

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

I came across this [picture](https://imgur.com/gallery/j7NXx), which I initially questioned and thought about posting to Skeptics. Then I thought they'll only tell me if this one case is true, but wouldn't it be great to know how true any "rule" really is? Today you're going program a skeptic-bot

**Challenge**

Write a program or function which when given a dictionary of valid words and a rule determines if the rule is well applied

**Rules**

- The dictionary is "words.txt" taken from [here](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words). Your submission must theoretically be able to review all words in the file, but for testing you may use a shortened list
- "Rules" come in the form `x before y except <before/after> z`.  Your submission may take that input in any reasonable form, some examples below
- Compliance is defined as: "There is an adjacent `x` and `y` in the word in the right order that are in the reverse order if before/after `z`"
- Non-compliance is defined as: "There is an adjacent `x` and `y` in the word in the incorrect order or they are not reverse if before/after `z`"
- Rules are evaluated case insensitive
- Output or return a [truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey#2194) value if the number of compliant words in the dictionary is greater than the number of non-compliant words, otherwise output a falsey value. Submissions cannot end in errors.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest submission in bytes wins

Example input:

```
["i","e","-","c"]  #list of values, "-" denotes "after"
[105,101,-99]    #list of values as ASCII numbers, "-99" denotes "after"
"ieac"           #string of values abbreviated
```

**Test Cases**

Below are sample cases as inputs, for clarity I list the matching words but this is not required

Example dictionary: `["caught", "lemon", "simplified", "queue", "qwerty", "believe", "fierce", "receive", "science", "foreign", "weird", "quit"]`

```
Input: "I before E except after C"
Compliant: simplified, believe, fierce, receive   
Noncompliant: science, foreign, weird       
Output: Truthy        

Input: "Q before U except before E"
Compliant: quit
Noncompliant: queue 
Output: Falsey

Input: "C before E except before E"
Compliant: fierce, receive, science
Noncompliant: 
Output: Truthy
```

Comment: Looks like your link died :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Python3, <strike>105</strike> 103 bytes

This is my first golf here so be kind =)

-2 bytes tanks to Chas Brown

```
lambda d,b,x,y,z:sum((x+y in i)-2*((z*b+x+y+z)[:3]in i)-(y+x in i)+2*((z*b+y+x+z)[:3]in i)for i in d)>0
```

Takes the dictionary `d` as any iterator of strings; a boolean 'b' (`True` being `after`); and the three letters `x,y,z` as Strings;

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBNb4MwDIbPy6@wsksomTStN6TuOGn33VoOIRjqCQLNRwv98ywBbd3FH49ev7Y8zv48mP3SHE5Lp/qqVlDLSk5ylvfChV6IKZ@BDFD28rYT4r6r8kjye3Ys9uXGxZxPmyT/lUTyX9IMFihJ6uz9dalJexqMsjMc4Mi1Cu3Zc8k77AcTs6N@7KghrGNzCRgw5RtaP8eiwo7wmlBUWJ0KixppRU4TmpXFlUhtsrsh2c2JPC@ZR@ddWnxiR06oufyyAddQysQuad@H6hxucaMa/@gqPbGSsWf4hOCwBn9GcKpHSO5aOQTlVvitrgoGE3u/9v3Qo/EwNHCz5Mm0jKXn2NChhArT1RIsutD59K/12II9jZaMF7wdfMElNOLxwsfUriPnRXLKMgkcpxG1xzoNbIbZ8gM)

**Explanation:** might add later

Comment: You can save a few bytes by replacing `...] in i` with `...]in i` in a couple of places. Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 210 bytes

```java
(D,a,b,c,f)->D.stream().filter(w->w.contains(a+b)&!w.contains(f?c+a+b:a+b+c)|w.contains(f?c+b+a:b+a+c)).count()>D.stream().filter(w->w.contains(b+a)&!w.contains(f?c+b+a:b+a+c)|w.contains(f?c+a+b:a+b+c)).count()
```

Takes the dictionary `D` as a `java.util.List<String>`; the three letters `a,b,c` as Strings; and whether it's after or before as a boolean `f` (truthy being 'after').

EDIT: Surprisingly enough using two `.matches` with regexes instead of the two times three `.contains` is longer. And creating variables for `f?c+a+b:a+b+c` and `f?c+b+a:b+a+c` is also [1 byte longer](https://tio.run/##hVNNb9swDL33V3A6DBas@Acka4oBOXbdocd1B5mhM6W2nEpUsqDLb89oO58Fgh5skfTjkx71vLRrO1rOX/dY2xjhh3X@/Q7AeaZQWSR46lKAn@WSkAGzpTQUiV1dPLrI3545OL@YwswMEdhjUB4DNGXb1mQ9VHoiZLs7eUW27BCewMM97LOZsaY0aCo9mr4f@vi@esDc5uVYnhxN6vMyt2N5cpwE4hQ8zIrIgWyT6aJytRw724ymmwJbzyImZtKsv365KLD@d5ElrSVJnjM9/YxK9r2mSldUfKaa7PaTTuYqlbXIPKhdt24OjWCzQeKv32D1MN8bY507ZNd6G7YyJk@bC9z3EOy2A2cfarGwsa8rtGnxh5VRNTWtlzW6ZlW7ytFckrdEibp1Q4G3EpRUO1p3JUEE7IJASK4vRXTk@1rVBnKLjm5DLgxMjpXuLxeASbY@n9soJ4iuD5XhkOgW7E0gaYBWto43cXigu8Jdeqqfct/26VANnFwLJ9vCybdwNu5wS8/byNQUbeJiJRiuvdhLQUndTECJORXQX6QVS5JVD8pW4iI1VgNCafmucszV@IVfWOW@wEttx3/gIGm3/w8).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hVNNb9swDL33V3A6DBbs@AekW4YCOW7docd1B5mhM6aKnEp0vGDtb89oO1/rEPQgiyIfSfHpeeW2brJaPO3Ru5Tgm@Pw5waAg1CsHRLc90eA79WKUACzlSaUrbAvv3KSTw8SOSxnMC9GC9zRqI4GFlXTeHIBanurxV5v9JPECSPcQ4DPsM/mhSuqAovaTmbzMkkkt85sWbPXe2TdZNaV2ATR26XM5ZX9@OHCUX/BXJ1TXTnalzeRKndTXRqxGmiDZPbdFor/v8W50MvV5qcW@9t@yk1beZ3yMOy24QWsNSsbmfnxE5wd6b3C6oJRuAku7pSlQN0F7i5Gt@vB2RtfKl0a/AZdu/wlpjCe1k3QPfF647lmWujhuaWW@r2jKDs1KvJM296liIi9EQmJB1dCpjD46iYSL/tyHXEcK7EYO7wtgJC2Pt@7MKyIPg9NIbGla7BnhbQjtHY@XcXhodw/uEtJDSwPae@SWsBJtHBSLZxkC2fdjq/0sEtC67JppdwoRnxQMRqoqOcEjCrAAP1G2ogeVBnG1aotMzUjwliNmxxzM32URzF5KPFytuMvcBjpdf8X)

**Explanation:**

```java
(D,a,b,c,f)->             // Method with List, 3 Strings, boolean parameters & boolean return
  D.stream()              //  Stream the given dictionary-List
   .filter(w->            //  Filter the words by:
     w.contains(a+b)      //   If the word contains `a+b`
      &!w.contains(f?     //   If the flag is true (after):
                   c+a+b  //    And the word does not contain `c+a+b`
                  :       //   Else (before):
                   a+b+c) //    And the word does not contain `a+b+c`
     |w.contains(f?       //   If the flag is true (after):
                  c+b+a   //    Or the word contains `c+b+a`
                 :        //   Else (before):
                  b+a+c)) //    Or the word contains `b+a+c`
   .count()               //  And get the amount of words left in the filtered result
  >                       //  And return whether this is larger than:
  D.stream()              //  Stream of the given dictionary again
   .filter(w->            //  Filtered by:
     w.contains(b+a)      //   If the word contains `b+a`
      &!w.contains(f?     //   If the flag is true (after):
                    c+b+a //    And the word does not contain `c+b+a`
                   :      //   Else (before):
                    b+a+c)//    And the word does not contain `b+a+c`
     |w.contains(f?       //   If the flag is true (after):
                  c+a+b   //    Or the word contains `c+a+b`
                 :        //   Else (before):
                  a+b+c)) //    Or the word contains `a+b+c`
   .count()               //  And get the amount of words left in the filtered result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>109</s> 107 bytes

```python
lambda D,x,y,r,c:sum((((' '+w+' ')[w.find(p)+3*r]!=c)^(p==y+x))*2-1for p in(x+y,y+x)for w in D if p in w)>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BboMwEEX3OcWUjXGYVkm6q0RX3CJNJWLGyUhgHAM1Pj21IYvWC@vPe55vG8Z7b06LLr@Wtu6uTQ0VzhjQofoYpi6PR4AofBFvefZvmk2TW1m8793lpVTyO7dlGYpZyv3p9ah7BxbY5HMRMNEEfARQAetVgZefh6WCEs6ZqqfbfcwQspa63qQwcGdb1kxNmh4TTbQGT24MKV2pZfpZYXzl1JocKeINDorJbDR@Tnxbaz2xezbymF12O@vYjKDzCgULFCTwgEIJ@Vc8opgEHpP@J9S28RTL8gs)

Takes Dictionary and rule input as `D,x,y,r,c` with `r=0` to mean 'before' and `r=1` to mean 'after'.